# What does byte['?'] mean in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a question. I don't know what does `byte['?']` means; it works for all the types of arrays but I'm curious about what it actually does.

```
private void copy(InputStream in, File file) {
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buf = new byte['?'];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception localException) {
}
```

Comment: in what context does that "work"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this doesn't mean anything at all.

Comment: there is a MASSIVE difference between `byte['?']` and `byte["?"]`. Dont re-type code, *copy* it.

Comment: Oh, sorry updated. Still waiting for an answer though.

Comment: you might want  to look at the charcode of `?`.

Comment: `'?'` is the same as `(char)63` and `char` in java is just an unsigned 16 bit quantity.

Comment: System.out.println((byte)'A'); // 65, surprise, surprise

Comment: If anyone used this in production code at a company, they should be given a final warning.'?' has a unicode codepoint of 63, and a character '?' used in this context is implicitly converted to an `int` with value 63.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `'?'` is a `char`. It can be converted to and integer `int` implicitly.

The `new byte[arraySize]` expects `arraySize` to be of type `int`. Therefore, `'?'` is converted to the integer, and the statement becomes:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[63];
```

because `63 == (int)'?'`.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't figure it out :P

Comment: `char` is a UTF-16 code unit. Only one UTF-16 code unit is needed for the Unicode codepoint "?" (U+003F) so it can be written as a `char` (`'?'`). `(int)'?'` == `(int)'\u003F'` == `63`. (Any similarity with ASCII is at best a distraction, and at worst leads people to not understand Java.)

Comment: @TomBlodget Well, yes, agreed. Javadoc for Character: "[the char datatype] are based on the original Unicode specification, which defined characters as fixed-width 16-bit entities". Whatever those things "really" are, your description is more true than my reference to ascii. But it doesn't really matter for '?'. The question is not really about code that does anything sophisticated with characters. This weird '?' looks like something from the international obfuscated C code contest to me... However, I fixed my answer.